# Include .scss dynamically from component constructor (not decorator) - Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, angular-material2

I need to apply a custom theme in Angular 4 using Angular Material theming, whose primary and accent color is obtained from a DB. For that, I add classes in the styles.scss for apply the theme, for example:

```
.light-red-pink {
     $custom-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-red);
     $custom-app-accent: mat-palette($mat-pink);
     $custom-app-theme: mat-light-theme($custom-app-primary, $custom-app-accent);
     @include angular-material-theme($custom-app-theme);
}
.light-lime-blue {
     $custom-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-lime);
     $custom-app-accent: mat-palette($mat-blue);
     $custom-app-theme: mat-light-theme($custom-app-primary, $custom-app-accent);
     @include angular-material-theme($custom-app-theme);
}
```

However, I have to add many classes (more than 300 classes and 2000 code lines) to apply all possibles themes, and this causes my project to load very slowly. I thought about separating the classes into separate .scss files, but I have some remaining questions:

Is it possible to dynamically include .scss files into a component?

Alternatively, how can I avoid loading so many styles?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution! For include .scss files, i had to add this line in the component's constructor:

```
require('style-loader!./path/to/my-theme.scss');
```

For apply the custom theme:

```
/** Constructor */
constructor(
    private themeService: ThemeService
) {
    const pathTheme = this.themeservice.getPath();
    require('style-loader!' + pathTheme);
}
```

And that's all!